# Solve eigenvalues-constrained optimization problem

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have the following constrained optimization problem

\begin{align}
\mathop{\text{min}}_\mathbf{Kp,Kd} && (\mathbf{Kd} - \mathbf{Kd_d})^2 + (\mathbf{Kp} - \mathbf{Kp_d})^2 \\
\text{subject to:} && \lambda_m\{\mathbf{Kp}\} > \mathbf{v1}\\
&& \lambda_m\{\mathbf{Kd}\} > \mathbf{v2}\\
&& \lambda_m\{\mathbf{Kd}\}*\lambda_m\{\mathbf{Kp}\} + \mathbf{n}*\lambda_m\{\mathbf{Kd}\} > \mathbf{v3}\\
\end{align}

Assume that the only unknown variables are the squared matrices $\mathbf{Kp,Kd}$, whereas $\mathbf{Kp_d,Kd_d}$ are known squared full rank matrices. For simplicity, we can assume that all the matrices are diagonal.
$\lambda_m$ denotes the smallest eigenvalue of its argument.
$\mathbf{v1},\mathbf{v2},\mathbf{v3},\mathbf{n}$ are known scalar.

Which approach can I use to solve such a problem? I am open to numerical methods as well.

---

EDIT: Since someone made me notice that dealing with matrices makes everything harder, I will take advantage of the fact that the matrices are diagonal to turn the problem into a scalar one.

Assume that $\mathbf{Kd},\mathbf{Kp},\mathbf{Kd_d},\mathbf{Kp_d}$ are diagonal $NxN$ positive definite matrices.
Let $\mathbf{kd_i}$ be the element in position $(i,i)$ of $\mathbf{Kd}$.
In the same way, $\mathbf{kp_i}$ is the element in position $(i,i)$ of $\mathbf{Kp}$.

Let $\mathbf{S_d}$ be the set containing all the elements in the diagonal of $\mathbf{Kd}$ and $\mathbf{S_p}$ be the set containing all the elements in the diagonal of $\mathbf{Kp}$

I can rewrite the problem as:

\begin{align}
\mathop{\text{min}} && \sum_{i=0}^N[(\mathbf{kd_i} - \mathbf{kd_{di}})^2 + (\mathbf{kp_i} - \mathbf{kp_{di}})^2] \\
\text{subject to:} && min(\mathbf{S_p}) > \mathbf{v1}\\
&& min(\mathbf{S_d}) > \mathbf{v2}\\
&& min(\mathbf{S_d})*min(\mathbf{S_p}) + \mathbf{n}*min(\mathbf{S_d}) > \mathbf{v3}\\
\end{align}

Comment: This problem is so hard. For multiple reasons. The first one the objective is a matrix! The second one constraints are strict inequalities and the last one there is a product of eigenvalues values which is not tractable.

Comment: @Youem Yes, indeed I wasn't able to find any suitable solution in the related scientific literature. By the way, I can assume that the matrix is diagonal, which allows me to simplify the problem into a scalar one. By doing that, the main problem becomes finding the smallest element of a set (as the elements of the matrix are actually the eigenvalues). Furthermore, since I'm willing to obtain an approximated solution, we can relax the "strict inequalities" assumption by setting ≤v1−ϵ where epsilon represents a small value. Does this help?

Comment: You need to simplify your objective because we cannot minimize a matrix. If every thing is a scalar your can write the problem as polynomial optimization problem.

Comment: Are $v_i$ positive?

Comment: All the values involved are nonnegative

Comment: This is such a confusing way of writing down an optimisation problem. Why not just say you have $2N$ scalar variables $x_i$ from $i=1,\ldots,2N$, a set of given values $c_i$ and you want to minimise $\sum_{i=1}^{2N} \left(x_i-c_i\right)^2$ subject to $x_i>v_1$ for $x_i$ from $i=1,\ldots,N$, $x_i>v_2$ for $x_i$ from $i=N+1,\ldots,2N$? You may need to think of a way to write the third condition (it's tricky in a comment) but this seems a lot clearer.

Comment: This might be what you're after: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program

Comment: @ChrisLewis You are right, the way you proposed seems much more straightforward. I think that I may express the third constraint as: for every pair of $kp$ and $kd$ I set $kp*kd + n*kd > v3$. At this point, I can simply use qcqp as you suggested, right?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand the question.
It seems you are trying to get the diagonal values of the resulting matrix as low as possible?
Lets look just at Kd- Kdd. each eigenvalue in Kd is larger than the minimum and positive as you said in the comments. then you just need to optimize |Kd_i - Kdd_i| , _i being the signifier for eigenvalue i.

Obviously you want to take Kd_i = Kdd_i, but that's not necessarily possible. If you can't take it so since Kdd_i < min(Kd eigenvalues) then you want to take Kd_i = min(Kd eigenvalues).

Same for Kp. Now you only have to solve the constraints at the bottom.
Am I missing something?

Comment: No, your observations are quite accurate. What's missing is how to solve the last constraint, but I think I've found the answer in the comments.